# Simulate typing text on a search bar and show autocomplete options

Tags: javascript, html, css, search

I want to simulate typing text on a search bar with pure javascript. The search bar has an autocomplete feature. So, Once you start writing letters, it shows options for words. I am  not sure but, I think the search bar must listen to some keyword event in order to show the options available for autocomplete, while it simulates the typing.
I have already achieved the automatic typing, but it does not show the autocomplete options.

This is my code:

```
let field = document.getElementById('search-field');
    field.select();
    field.focus();
    field.value = "";
let text = "smart tv";
let l = text.length;
let current = 0;
let time = 1000;


myButton.addEventListener('click', function(){
  writeText();
})

let writeText = function(){
    field.value+=text[current];
      if(current < l-1) {
        current++;
        setTimeout(function(){ writeText() },time);
      } else {
        field.setAttribute('value',field.value);
      }
}


field.addEventListener('keydown', (e) => {
  console.log(e);
  console.log('type fired!');
})

field.dispatchEvent(new KeyboardEvent('keydown', {
  'key': 'a'
}));
```

Comment: You're setting the value of the input field, which technically is not a simulation of the typing and does not trigger the 'keydown' event you're listening for.

Comment: Ok, It really makes sense what you say. but How do I set the word I want to get simulated?

Comment: The way you set the value is alright. Once the recursive function is done you should trigger an event for the object (field if I understood correctly) the autocomplete's listening to. However, without knowing how the autocomplete functionality is invoked it's hard to answer. Maybe you could elaborate a bit, perhaps even provide a working example (of what you have so far)?